# Conditional format if column contains value and those rows contain another value

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I am looking for a way to conditional format (Highlight) cells in a column using 2 conditions:

1. If Cell value is present in column A
2. If the value in the corresponding "B" cell contain a specific value

Example:

Step 1

- is D1 present in column A - **YES**

Step 2

- Do Cells B1, B4, or B8 contain the value ("asd") - **YES**

*Note: A1, A4, and A8 ar all the cell that contain the value in D1 (in this case 123), and the value "asd" is intended to be any value inputted by me manually*

**Result highlight cell D1**

[image]

**Another Note:**

*COUNTIFS() wouldn't work in this scenario because the intent is to be able to scan barcodes into column D and ask the question for all 1000 barcodes as they are scanned individually, is this barcode an "asd". if it is place the box on this pallet, if not place the box on another pallet.

I would also like to make the hard coded value dynamic to account for potential typos, say I am scanning for "asd" but the value in column "B" was mistakenly written as "asdf".*

Comment: use `=COUNTIFS(A:A,D1,B:B,"asd")>0`

Comment: the countifs() wouldn't work in this scenario because the intent is to be able to scan barcodes into column D and ask the question for all 1000 barcodes as they are scanned individually, is this barcode an "asd". if it is place the box on this pallet, if not place the box on another pallet

Comment: That would be the rule for the conditional formatting and it would work as long as it finds a match where both a equals the scan and b = 'asd'

Comment: for wildcard: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,D1,B:B,"*"&"asd"&"*")>0`

Comment: That makes alot of sense, and its working as I needed. not sure why it was so difficulty for me to figure this out lol.

Comment: @ScottCraner If you want to write this up as an answer I can accept it Thanks again, I am able to change the formula and add additional criteria, and I am baffled how I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 2):

Use this conditional formatting formula on column D (adjust ranges if needed).

```
=AND($D1<>"",IF(SUM(--(IF($A$1:$A$8=D1,$B$1:$B$8,"")="asd")),TRUE,FALSE))
```

Note, `asd` is hard-coded in the formula. It might be a better idea to reference another cell that has contains `asd`, so it will be easier to update if needed.

(The golden rule of excel is use cell references when you can! Never hard-code values into the formula)

---

Explanation:

This `IF(SUM(--(IF($A$1:$A$8=D1,$B$1:$B$8,"")="asd")),TRUE,FALSE)` sees if any cell in column B (which is adjacent to the column A cell which matches column D) is equal to `asd`.

`--(TRUE, FALSE)` turns into `(1,0)` behind the scenes, so you can add up if any value in column B matches `asd`, and if the sum is greater than 1, then you know you have a match.

Comment: In the IF(SUM(--(IF($A$1:$A$8=D1,$B$1:$B$8,"")="asd")),TRUE,FALSE) I was messing around with it and trying to make the hard coded value "asd" dynamic to account for potential extra spaces or symbols I tried adding the wild card and it didn't work, any ideas?

Comment: sure. replace "asd" (including the double quotes surrounding asd, and type (or select) a different cell which you would like to reference, for example: IF(SUM(--(IF($A$1:$A$8=D1,$B$1:$B$8,"")=$E$1)),TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: Although, better use Scott's answer. When I saw you write that countifs won't work, I just created a different formula that is similar. But his is more straightforward

Comment: Thanks Dave, I appreciate you supplying the work-around, you did deliver exactly what I asked, if @scottcraner doesn't end up posting his suggested as answer I will accept yours because it does in fact answer my question.